# finding positive vector that multiplied by matrix give positive vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi,
I'm looking to solve the following mathematical problem

I have a given matrix $A$. i want to know if there is a vector $x$ that satisfy two conditions:

1. the coordinates of $x$ are positive.
2. the product $Ax$ gives a vector that all his coordinates are positive

is there a mathematical name for that kind of vector? (positive vector?)

Comment: I do not know if it has a name, but I have seen it used a couple of times in M-matrix literature. Is your $A$ perchance a [Z-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_%28mathematics%29)?

Comment: I'm curios about the general case, but in the case i research now its a Z-matrix / L-matrix (the diagonal is positive and non-diagonal are negative or zero). @Fredrico thanks for the definition. it describes well the A matrix. 

Comment: If you have $x$, you can scale it so that all coordinates of $x$ and $Ax$ are greater than $1$. Thus, the existence of $x$ can be expressed in terms of linear programming as feasibility of the system $\vec x\ge\vec1$, $Ax\ge\vec1$. In particular, the linear programming duality may shed some light on the existence of $x$.

Comment: Did not know before the magical abilities of Linear programming.
solved my problems with tools from that field.
@Emil - thanks.

Comment: If your matrix is a Z-matrix, then such an $x$ can also be chosen as the eigenvector relative to the smallest eigenvalue. This might be faster, especially for large matrices.

Comment: @iko: You’re welcome, I’m glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

For the vector, not that I know. But a matrix $A$ for which such a $x$ exists is called *semipositive*.

Some useful references as starting points for a literature search: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081089408818329, and the book by Berman and Plemmons *Nonnegative matrices in the mathematical sciences*.